# parent id to many child or one id to many child fk

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want one PK to many FK for example

for example my parent table

```
   user_id | name |
       1   | foo  |
```

this is my child table

```
child_id|user_id|name |
    1   |   1   | bar |
    2   |   1   |  a  |
```

for more details just refer to this[image]

about the image i can **ONLY ADD ONE** every fk but i want one fk many data.

here is another details just in case.
[image]

Comment: So, what do you need? A select?

Comment: @Philipp no what i want 1 pk to many fk

Comment: @Philipp but what i got is 1 pk to 1 fk

Comment: Post the schema of your tables.

Comment: @KaeL what do you mean?